# OutOfMemoryError on evaluation of a 2D stream

Tags: scala, stream, lazy-evaluation

Why does the following lead to `OutOfMemoryError`?

```
scala> Stream.tabulate(3, 4)(_ + _)
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Stream[scala.collection.immutable.Stream[Int]] = Stream(Stream(0, ?), ?)

scala> res0.length
```

The same happens on application of `size` and `force` methods.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. "res0.length" outputs "3" for me. No out of memory... OS X 10.6.6, Scala 2.8.1, Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 19.1-b02-334, mixed mode).

Comment: @Mitchell: I am using Scala 2.8.0.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a bug in 2.8: "Stream.tabulate creates an infinite stream"

Have a look.
http://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/ticket/3508